# C++ wndproc в классе

Tags: c++

Делаю обертку вокруг winapi окна, нужно затащить wndproc в класс а он статический. Вобщем WindowProc не работает почемуто.. pwnd null

```
#pragma once
#include "windows.h"
class Window {
protected:
  HWND hwnd;
public:
LRESULT WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (message)
  {

  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
  }

  return 0;
}
static LRESULT CALLBACK internal_WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM 
  wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  Window* pWnd;

  if (message == WM_NCCREATE)
  {
    LPCREATESTRUCT cs = reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam);
    pWnd = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(cs->lpCreateParams);

    SetLastError(0);
    if (!SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR> 
    (pWnd)))
    {
      int i = 1;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    pWnd = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA));
  }

  if (pWnd)
  {
    return pWnd->WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
  }
  else
  {
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
  }
}
Window() {

WNDCLASSW windowClass;

windowClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_PARENTDC;
windowClass.lpfnWndProc = &internal_WndProc;
windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
windowClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
windowClass.hIcon = NULL;
windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, (LPTSTR)IDC_IBEAM);
windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
windowClass.lpszClassName = L"MainWindowClass";

RegisterClassW(&windowClass);

this->hwnd = CreateWindowW(L"MainWindowClass", L"Window", (
  WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX),
  GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - 400,
  GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - 300, 800, 600, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);

ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
}
};
```

Comment: "pwnd null". Не понял. А каким еще оно должно быть? У вас последний аргумент `CreateWindow` - `0`. Это и есть ваш `cs->lpCreateParams`. Передали ноль - получили ноль. Все как и должно быть.

Comment: @AnT если я создаю главное окно оно должно же быть 0

Comment: Почему "должно же быть"?

Comment: @MikeWaters, [CreateWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa#parameters)

Comment: @AnT this туда надо?

Comment: @Mike Waters: Вам должно быть виднее, что туда надо, но, судя по коду, да, туда надо `this`.

Comment: @AnT если там this то окно не показывает